# a stacked/overlay div that align on right side without using px

Tags: css, vuejs2, overlay, z-index

I have am using a div as a help button. The button is right aligned using float.
Now when 'popHelp' pops up it is aligned on the left side.
How do I align it on the right side?
**  @click="popHelp" hides and shows the help

```
<div class="help3d">
  <div
    @click="popHelp">
    <span>{{ helpLabel }}</span>
  </div>
  <div v-if="showHelp" id="popHelp">
    {{ helpL1 }}
  </div>
</div>


.help3d {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1 solid #000;
  background-color: #c88;
  position: static;
}
#popHelp {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #844;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
```

if I try to use relative, the popHelp displaces any div under it. I want it to overlay it

Comment: Do you mean popHelp is left aligned with respect to the page or help3d?

Comment: popHelp is now left aligned with help3d, I want it right aligned with help3d

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this CSS fixes your issue

```
.help3d {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1 solid #000;
  background-color: #c88;
  position: relative;
}

#popHelp {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #844;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better.  Now the right side is aligned with the right side of help3d.  But the left side is aligned to the left side of help3d.  I would like the left side to expand left.
I noticed two "right", one auto and one 0.

I think if I do a third div that is the correct width that might solve the problem.

```
<div class="help3d">
  <div class="helpBtn"
    @click="popHelp">
    <span>{{ helpLabel }}</span>
  </div>
  <div v-if="showHelp" id="popHelp">
    <div v-for="line in helpLines">
      <span>{{ helpL1 }}</span><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I will play with help3d width.
More later
Thanks

Comment: Yes I did it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this CSS fixes your issue

```
#popHelp {
   background-color: #844;
   color: #fff;
   display: block;
   float: right;
   right: auto;
   text-align: left;
   top: auto;
   z-index: 20;
}
```